# What is the dual of generating Boolean subalgebra by subexpressions of a modal formula?

Tags: lo.logic, duality, modal-logic

I am supposed to be answering this question rather than asking it but I really cannot figure out.

There is a variation on Stone duality linking algebraic and (descriptive) Kripke semantics for (normal only?) modal logics. On the algebraic side, we have modal algebras, i. e. pairs $(B,\Box)$ where $B$ is a Boolean algebra and $\Box$ is a multiplicative operator on it. On the Kripke side we have descriptive Kripke frames, i. e. pairs $(X,R)$ where $X$ is a Stone space and $R$ is a binary relation on $X$ such that $R^{-1}C$ is clopen for any clopen subset $C$ of $X$.

Thanks to this duality there is a whole exciting dictionary translating key concepts and facts between these two worlds. For example, free modal algebras correspond to canonical models, inducing modalities on finite subalgebras of $B$ correspond to inducing relations on finite continuous images of $X$, etc.

There is one really important construction though "on the left" which I have problems translating "to the right side". One frequently needs the following: given an instantiation $\varphi(b_1,...,b_n)$ of a modal formula in $(B,\Box)$, generate finite Boolean subalgebra of $B$ by values of subexpressions of $\varphi$. Although this sounds very syntactic, it can be also made more algebraically flavored: you seek a smallest finite Boolean subalgebra containing the $b_i$ and endowed with a modality (but not necessarily modal subalgebra) in such a way that $\varphi(b_1,...,b_n)$ computed in that subalgebra is the same.

My question is whether there is some recognizable construct on descriptive frames that is dual to the above?

My attempts did not go very far. Clearly specifying $b_1,...,b_n$ means a homomorphism from the free $n$-generated modal algebra to $B$, so dually the initial data consist of an $n$-model, i. e. a p-morphism $\pi:X\to\mathscr K(n)$ from $X$ to the $n$-canonical model, together with a specified clopen $C_\varphi$ of $\mathscr K(n)$ which then produces a clopen $C=\pi^{-1}C_\varphi$ of $X$. From that data we seemingly must produce continuous $R$-preserving map (but not necessarily a p-morphism) from $X$ to some finite Kripke frame $F$ and a p-morphism (?) from $F$ to $\mathscr K(n)$ which factor $\pi$ and give the same $C$, but I am not sure.

**Update**

After discussing the answer below, it now seems that the question reduces to the following.

Let $\mathscr F(n)$ be the free modal algebra on specified free generators $p_1,...,p_n$, and let $\mathscr K(n)$ be its dual (canonical model). Then for any $\varphi(p_1,...,p_n)\in\mathscr F(n)$ we get a uniquely determined finite Boolean subalgebra $B_\varphi\subseteq\mathscr F(n)$ generated by all subexpressions of $\varphi$. Dually this gives a finite quotient $\mathscr K(n)\twoheadrightarrow F_\varphi$ (not necessarily a p-morphism for any choice of $R$ on $F_\varphi$). Then one must describe this $F_\varphi$ explicitly or, even better, characterize it by some universal property.

Answer (score 3):

Update:

If we were looking for the smallest finite Boolean subalgebra containing the $b_i$ and endowed with an arbitrary modality (but not necessarily modal subalgebra) in such a way that $\varphi(b_1,...,b_n)$ computed in that subalgebra is the same, we would get:

A finite Kripke frame $F$ together with a surjective continuous map $f:X \to F$ for which there is a p-morphism $g:F \to \mathscr{K}(n)$ such that:

$\mu gf=\mu \pi$,

and $f^{-1}(g^{-1}(C_\varphi))= \pi^{-1}(C_\varphi)=C$.

Where $\mathscr{K}_B(n)$ is the Stone space dual to the free Boolean algebra on $n$-generators and $\mu: \mathscr{K}(n) \to \mathscr{K}_B(n)$ is the continuous map dual to the homomorphism sending the generator $p_i$ of the free Boolean algebra to the generator $p_i$ of the free modal algebra.

With the following universal property: for every finite Kripke frame $F'$ and surjective continuous map $f':X \to F'$ that satisfy those properties, there is a surjective map $h: F' \to F$ such that $hf'=f$. Such a morphism $h$ is necessarily unique.

---

But this is not enough because nothing guarantees that this subalgebra contains the values of the subformulas of $\varphi$.

Without loss of generality we can assume that $\varphi$ contains only the operator $\Diamond$. What we want is that if $\psi_1, \ldots, \psi_k$ are the subformulas of $\varphi$ such that $\Diamond \psi_i$ is still a subformula of $\varphi$ then $\Diamond$ in the subalgebra coincides with $\Diamond$ in $B$ on the values of the $\psi_i$'s.

Which can be dually translated by asking that for all $i=1, \ldots, k$:

$f^{-1}(g^{-1}( R^{-1}( C_{\psi_i})))= \pi^{-1}(R^{-1}( C_{\psi_i}))$

where $C_{\psi_i}$ is the clopen of $\mathscr{K}(n)$ corresponding to $\psi_i$. Note that $\pi^{-1}(R^{-1}( C_{\psi_i}))=R^{-1}( \pi^{-1}(C_{\psi_i}))$ because $\pi$ is a p-morphism.

---

I think you are right in saying that we can just restrict to the case $B=\mathscr{K}(n)$. So in that case we would get:

A finite Kripke frame $F$ together with a surjective continuous map $f:\mathscr{K}(n) \to F$ for which there is a p-morphism $g:F \to \mathscr{K}(n)$ such that:

$\mu gf=\mu$,

$f^{-1}(g^{-1}(C_\varphi))= C_\varphi$,

and $f^{-1}(g^{-1}( R^{-1}( C_{\psi_i})))= R^{-1}( C_{\psi_i})$

for all $i=1, \ldots, k$. Where $\mathscr{K}_B(n)$ is the Stone space dual to the free Boolean algebra on $n$-generators and $\mu: \mathscr{K}(n) \to \mathscr{K}_B(n)$ is the continuous map dual to the homomorphism sending the generator $p_i$ of the free Boolean algebra to the generator $p_i$ of the free modal algebra.

With the following universal property: for every finite Kripke frame $F'$ and surjective continuous map $f':\mathscr{K}(n) \to F'$ that satisfy those properties, there is a surjective map $h: F' \to F$ such that $hf'=f$. Such a map $h$ is necessarily unique.

---

I feel this is still not a satisfactory answer because the construction is too convoluted and too syntactic.

Comment: Thank you! Questions: what are requirements for maps $f$, $f'$, $h$? Continuity? Relation preservation? Relation reflection?

Comment: And, does such universal $g$ always exist? Because in general image of $\pi$ is not necessarily finite, right? Whereas that construction (of finite Boolean subalgebra generated by subexpressions) can be done always.

Comment: Oh right, we need to ask for continuity of $f$ and $f'$. Since the domain of $h$ is a finite Kripke frame (whose Stone topology is discrete), there is no need to ask for continuity of $h$. I don't think we need to require anything about relation preservation or reflection either since their duals are Boolean algebras embedding that don't need to preserve $\Box$.

Comment: Yes, the image of $\pi$ is not necessarily finite (we can take $X= \mathscr{K}(n)$ and $\pi$ the identity map). I don't see any simple argument showing the existence of $F,f$ and $g$ directly without moving to the algebra side and coming back. I'm not really familiar with the algebraic construction of such a subalgebra, so I might be missing some insight. For sure if $g$ exists then it is unique as a consequence of $gf=\pi$ because $f$ is surjective.

Comment: I edited the answer by adding the continuity requirement for $f$ and $f'$.

Comment: Sorry I still don't understand the second part: the finite subalgebra can be always constructed, even if the image of $\pi$ is infinite. I think this means that $gf=\pi$ is too restrictive, no?

Comment: You are absolutely right. Since we're not building a modal subalgebra, $gf=\pi$ is not necessarily true. It needs to be $(gf)^{-1}(C_{b_i})=\pi^{-1}(C_{b_i})$  for the clopens $C_{b_i}$ corresponding to $b_i \in \mathscr{F}(n)$, where $\mathscr{F}(n)$ is the free modal algebra on $n$ generators dual to $\mathscr{K}(n)$. Let $\mathscr{F}_B(n)$ be the free Boolean algebra on $n$ generators and $\mathscr{K}_B(n)$ be its dual. There is $\mu:\mathscr{K}(n) \to \mathscr{K}_B(n)$ continuous map dual to the hom sending $b_i$ to $b_i$. I think we can ask that $\mu gf=\mu \pi$, instead of $gf=\pi$.

Comment: This looks closer. Still I think one needs a larger algebra since some subexpressions of $\varphi$ involve boxes and so possibly cannot be expressed by boolean operations alone from $b_i$...

Comment: I think I'm understanding what's wrong with this construction. At the moment I'm considering any modality on the subalgebra. I actually want the modality induced by the modality on $B$. Let me restrict to the S4 case for the moment. I assume that $R$ is a pre-order. If $D$ is a clopen in $F$ we want that $f^{-1}(R^{-1}D)$ is the smallest clopen downset containing $f^{-1}(D)$ which is saturated with respect to $f$. Requiring that $f$ is $R$-preserving or that $f$ is $R$-reflecting don't seem to be enough. It is true if $f$ is both $R$-preserving and reflecting but then it would be a p-morphism.

Comment: Since a Boolean subalgebra of a modal algebra has an induced operator, for any $X$ modal space and $F$ finite set, any surjective continuous map $f:X \to F$ induces an order on $F$. I think that order is defined in this way: for $a,b \in F$, $a R b$ iff $\exists x,y \in X$ s.t. $x R y$ and $f(x)=a$, $f(y)=b$. So I think we need to require this condition for $f$ which is a bit stronger than $R$-preserving but doesn't imply that $f$ is a p-morpshim. I edited my answer.

Comment: With filtrations, there are methods to put "half-compatible" box on a finite Boolean subalgebra; there are many such, and there is one "largest" and one "smallest" such box. I think they correspond to these $R$-preserving and $R$-reflecting cases.

Comment: As for your last version - I am not sure but I think now your requirement (that $\mu gf=\mu\pi$) might be too weak. What came to my mind after thinking on your answer is this: your $\mu$ corresponds to the Boolean subalgebra generated by $b_1$, ..., $b_n$, while we in fact need a larger (but still finite) subalgebra generated by subexpressions of $\varphi$. And I am precisely after describing *this one* in dual terms.

Comment: One more thing that came to my mind: in fact maybe the shorter (and more correct?) way is, after generating the corresponding subalgebra in $\mathscr F(n)$ and describing the corresponding finite quotient $\mathscr K(n)\twoheadrightarrow F$, simply pass to the image of the composite $X\to\mathscr K(n)\twoheadrightarrow F$?

Comment: I think I will add this to the question since it somehow narrows the search.

Comment: Yes, that seems better. We can just look at the Boolean subalgebra generated by the subexpressions of $\varphi$ in $\mathscr{F}(n)$ and then the image of that subalgebra under $\mathscr{F}(n) \to B$ has to be the Boolean subalgebra of $B$ generated by the values of the subexpressions of $\varphi$.

Comment: I'm commenting here instead of commenting the question because I don't have enough reputation to do that. There is one fact stated in the question that I don't understand fully: "the subalgebra generated by the values of the subexpressions coincides with the smallest finite Boolean subalgebra containing the $b_i$'s and endowed with a modality (but not necessarily modal subalgebra) in such a way that $\varphi(b_1, \ldots ,b_n)$ computed in that subalgebra is the same". What are the constraints on the choice of the modality on the subalgebra? I'm almost sure that we cannot pick any modality.

Comment: Since the modality is normal and the subalgebra is finite, it suffices to define, say, $\Diamond$ on atoms. There is a finite number of possibilities; among them, pick only those which give boxes and diamonds occurring in subexpressions of $\varphi$ and are arbitrary otherwise. I believe in this set you do have largest and smallest modality in terms of elementwise comparison of values. What I am up to is in a sense just this - dual description of the corresponding $R$ on the corresponding finite set. Preferably by a universal property.

Comment: Of course if you have an example when this set of candidates is empty it would be great and would settle the whole question.

Comment: I'm sorry, what I meant by "we cannot pick any modality" is that we cannot pick an arbitrary modality on the subalgebra. In fact it's easy to come up with a counterexample in which the two subalgebras don't coincide by taking the trivial modality . I agree that the whole problem boils down to the dual description of these modalities.

Comment: I see. Yes the key requirement is that  any applications of $\Box$ or $\Diamond$ involved in subexpressions of $\varphi$ must be preserved in the subalgebra.